# Getting error 'context must be a dict rather than set.' when trying to retrieve single object where id=id in django Model

Tags: python, django, model

I can't make work my detail function to simply retrieve all fields of only one Model element.

my code is :

views.py

```
def band_detail(request, id):
    band = Band.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,
                  'bands/band_detail.html',
                  {'band', band })
```

in urls.py I wrote:

```
path('bands/<int:id>/', views.band_detail)
```

So, when I am going to /bands/{id} it should show me my band_details.html page :

```
{% extends 'listings/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h1> {{ band.name }} </h1>

    {% if band.active %}

        <h2> Active : <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i> </h2>

    {% else %}

        <h2> Active : <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i> </h2>

    {% endif %}
            

{% endblock %}
```

but instead I get a typeError telling me : 'context must be a dict rather than set.'

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4R9x.jpg)

I guess this is due to the way I retrieve my Band object from id. But I can't wrap my mind around. That is why I am coming for a lil help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is so clear `context must be a dict rather than set`, the context should be `{'band': band}` not `{'band', band}` in your `views.py`

Answer (score 2):

You have a context error! because the context must be a dictionary.

```
def band_detail(request, id):
   band = Band.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,
              'bands/band_detail.html',
               context={'band': band })
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code lies in the way you are passing data to the template. The dictionary you're passing to the render function is not formatted correctly. You should use a key-value pair to pass data to the template, where the key is the variable name you want to use in the template and the value is the actual data.